# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser returns blank images

Tags: php, google-play, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm using the `SimpleHtmlDom` library (version 1.5 ($Rev: 196 $)) to parse pages from the `Google Play` to obtain screenshots. The problem is **sometimes** it returns blank images (`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw`) instead of app screenshots (e.g. `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SLp7-1W6c-LIl5nJkQWrYIb5i7b4XJwdjIox9CtnmRZF_tlWixLSsFo2vzXO6gbbOg`).

The code:

```
include_once('SimpleHtmlDom.php');

$googleplay = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=';
$application = 'com.nolesh.android.livewallpapers.quasar';

$html = $googleplay.$application.'&hl=en_EN';

$html = file_get_html($html);

$screenshots = array();
foreach($html->find('button img[itemprop="image"]') as $screenshot){            
    //truncate the size parameter from the end of string (=h310)
    $pos = strpos($screenshot->src, '=');
    $screenshots[] = substr($screenshot->src, 0, $pos);   
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Those are base64 encoded images. You need to strip the front part off up to the comme and base64 decode the rest

Comment: @pguardiario, I know that they are base64 encoded images. The problem is they should not be here. I expect to get the correct links to the images, not blank images encoded to base64. It's very strange, but now I get only 2 valid links. The rest links are base64 blank images. I even tried the 3rd party implementation [Google Play Scraper](https://github.com/raulr/google-play-scraper) and got the same result.